# ASP.NET is loading and unloading assemblies every time and it is taking a lot of time

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an ASP.NET Page that is super slow, its a single page application written in .NET 4.x.  The problem with it is that it seems to load and unload assemblies on every single call!  This is causing it to really be slow.  On average it takes about 30 seconds tot a full minute.

My question is: How do I pre-load all of the assemblies that its trying to load?  Will this prevent the assemblies being unloaded?

Comment: The [tag:assembly] tag is for questions about assembly language, not .NET assemblies.

Comment: Thanks, this is funny, people are quick to point out that my questions are out of scope, or other things related.  But this one is a funny one, where the assembly is not clearly defined haaha.  Not complaining just an FYI I do appreciate the solid structure.  I just hope someone can help!